# Jasmine throws exception when try to mock an angular factory

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, jasmine

I'm using jasmine-rails (Jasmine 2.3.4) and angularjs-rails (angular 1.4.7)

I have Jasmine and angular working and can test my controllers and factories. However when I try to mock a factory with

```
  beforeEach module('myApp', ($provide) ->
    $provide.factory('myFactory', () -> {})
  )
```

Jasmine throws the error

> this.expectationResultFactory is not a function

I can't seem to track down why, can anyone give me a clue?